# firefox renders unexpected, using background-image linear-gradient and background-size

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, background-image, linear-gradients

I want to use css to make grid background

my css code is below:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to right,
  var(--gantt-main-color-split) 0, var(--gantt-main-color-split) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 30px,
  var(--gantt-main-color-split) 30px, var(--gantt-main-color-split) 31px, transparent 31px, transparent 60px,
  var(--gantt-main-color-split) 60px, var(--gantt-main-color-split) 61px, var(--gantt-main-color-fill) 61px, var(--gantt-main-color-fill) 90px,
  var(--gantt-main-color-split) 90px, var(--gantt-main-color-split) 91px, var(--gantt-main-color-fill) 91px, var(--gantt-main-color-fill) 120px,
  var(--gantt-main-color-split) 120px, var(--gantt-main-color-split) 121px, transparent 121px, transparent 150px,
  var(--gantt-main-color-split) 150px, var(--gantt-main-color-split) 151px, transparent 151px, transparent 180px,
  var(--gantt-main-color-split) 180px, var(--gantt-main-color-split) 181px, transparent 181px, transparent 210px);
background-size: 210px;

--gantt-main-color-split: #E7E8E9;
--gantt-main-color-fill: #F4F5F7;
```

and chrome renders same as i expected.
[image: chrome renders correct]

But firefox renders different, which has some lines lost.
[image: firefox renders incorrect]

If i delete the line `background-size: 210px`, all lines show in firefox.
[image]

How to resolve this problem?
How to make firefox renders same as chrome, using both `background-image: linear-gradient...` and `background-size`?